# Can I receive local or push notifications to my email address?

Tags: notifications, apns

Can I receive local and/or push notifications to my email account instead of as a notification that appears on my iPhone?

I want to receive the local and push notifications for some apps but I don't want to necessarily receive them as pop-up notifications on my iPhone screen, but would rather access them in my inbox when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No.

iOS does not have any way for you to redirect notifications.

It may be possible to change how *some* notifications are sent, and have them sent to you via [Boxcar](http://boxcar.io) or something similar, but that is going to be limited to a very small subset of applications or services which are designed to offer alternatives. Twitter and Facebook come to mind.